# AWS S3 upload: The AWS Access Key Id does not exist in our records

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

There are quite a number of questions on stackoverflow with this error message, but none seems to be my case.

So, my problem is, I need to be able to upload a file directly from browser to S3 without going through server. To do that, I:

1. generate a signature on the server and send it to frond end.
2. Front end use the signature to upload files to S3.

Things work fine locally when I run the server on my local machine, but does not work when it runs on beanstalk. The problem is in my local, I have explicit ~/.aws/credentails which contains access key and access secret. But on beanstalk, we do it through IAM role, so the code to get credentials for either case is:

```
@Bean
public AWSCredentials awsCredentials() {
        DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain credProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        return credProvider.getCredentials();
}
```

As far as I know, when running locally, DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain just reads credentials from ~/.aws/credentials file, and when running on beanstalk it kinda generate access key and access secret based on the IAM role (valid for a short time, not sure how long, maybe a few hours).
When the server (which generate the signature) running on beanstalk, I got the error message from S3:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
<Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
```

Any idea why this is happening?